# Maintaining Certain Variables when using UglifyJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp, uglifyjs

I have a custom script that uses jQuery with the shorthand `$("selector")`notation. When I run my script through Uglify, the `$` gets changed to a random letter, like a "e" or something, causing my jQuery functions in my script to break. How can I ensure that the `$` doesn't get changed? I'm using Gulp for build, so is this something I need to set in my gulpfile?

Comment: have you try  --reserved-names?  https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone that may see this in the future, I passed `mangled: false` as an option when using the `uglify` task in my gulpfile to solve this.